# Convert SQL Statement to Linq

Tags: entity-framework, linq

This is my sample query

```
Select id from employee where id in
(select employeeid from employeecenter where CenterCodeId in 
(select CenterCodeId from employeecenter where employeeid=40))
```

How can we acheive the above using Linq

```
//Gets all the centerCodeIds allotted to an employee
Session["LoggedUserId"] = 40;
List<int> _centerCodeIds = _cmn.GetCenterEmpwise(Convert.ToInt32(Session["LoggedUserId"]))
                           .Select(x => x.Id).ToList();

//Get all employees having the above centercodids
List<int> _employeeIds = _db.EmployeeCenters
                        .Where(x => _centerCodeIds.Any(cc => x.Id == cc))
                        .Select(x => x.Employee.Id).ToList();
```

Comment: @teovankot my bad ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is:

```
List<int> _employeeIds = _db.EmployeeCenters.Where(x => _db.EmployeeCenters
                        .Where(y => y.EmployeeId == 40)
                        .Select(y => y.CenterCodeId)
                        .Contains(x.CenterCodeId))
                      .Select(x => x.EmployeeId)
                      .ToList();
```

But are you sure that you need second sub select in your Query?